# Cannot see the navbar on image (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to mention that I`m a beginner. ^^ I also want to mention that if I remove the div part at the beginning of the code block:

```
 div {
        background-image: url('./images/castle.png'); `I removed this line`
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
```

I`m able to see the navbar menu, but if I keep it, I only see the background image. I don't know what to do to be able to see the menu over the image.
Below you can see the code lines.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<style>
   

    h1 {
        color: orangered;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    img {
        background-size: cover;

    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .bg-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 380px;  
    }
    

    .bg img {
        background-image: url('./images/castle.png');
        min-height: 380px;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
   
    .container {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 20px;
        width: auto;
    }
   
    .topnav {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
   
    .topnav a {
        float: left;
        color: crimson;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }

    
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="bg-container">
    <div class="bg-img"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
            <div class="topnav">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
               
            </div>
         </div>
     
        

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.php)?

Comment: Yes, the index is 1 right now, also someone posted a fix and then deleted the post, I tried what that guy posted and still not working.

Comment: If you put a `z-index` greater than the `navbar `and it still didn't work, could you post the **entire HTML code** (concerning the navbar and the div in question) and not just the styling?

Comment: Sure, but it will not allow me to post the entire code here.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<style>

    h1 {
        color: orangered;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    img {
        background-size: cover;

    }

Comment: body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .bg-container {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 380px;  
    }
    

    .bg img {
        background-image: url('./images/castle.png');
        min-height: 380px;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

Comment: .container {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 20px;
        width: auto;
    }
   
    .topnav {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }
   
    .topnav a {
        float: left;
        color: crimson;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

Comment: .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
    }

    
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="bg-container">
    <div class="bg-img"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
            <div class="topnav">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
               
            </div>
         </div>
     
        

</body>

</html>

Comment: To add the code you should have edited your question by pressing **edit**. Don't add full codes in comments. I managed to more or less see what the result is like. A question arises... why are you using `background-image: url('./images/castle.png')`; both on the `div` tag and the `bg-img` class. What exactly is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: I edited the post and I added the code, I removed that div part you`re mentioning.

Comment: What I want to do is to add a navbar menu over a background image using CSS and HTML, from what I know it`s called "Navbar on image"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the *background image* you can do in different ways:

- One would be to use an element of type `img` using the `posiztion: absolute`, relative to the `body` or however to the *element you want*.
- The second way is to set it as `background-image` directly from the **CSS** properties.

To make the `navbar` you should learn to use [flex-box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp), it is very useful in different situations. To remove the `margins` and `paddings` use `*`*(CSS universal selector)* and if you want also use [box-sizing: border-box;](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://a.cdn-hotels.com/gdcs/production12/d1130/83f1c8c6-e12d-4e69-8433-c5bbc90b5ad6.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem .8rem;
  background: #333;
}

.navbar h1 {
    color: orangered;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    color: crimson;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>   
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  </head>
  <body>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <h1>Welcome to my page</h1>
            <div class="nav-links">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try the steps.
Thank you! ^^